# Cisco site-to-site vpn configuration

Tags: cisco-asa, vpn

Assume the current configuration has a headquarter and remote offices that connect using a VPN client (Cisco AnyConnect).
We want to eliminate the use of the VPN client for the users' workstation. So, my plan is to install a Cisco ASA on the remote offices and with the proper configuration, being able to connect to the headquarters, directly.
Is this something that could be done? If yes, where should I concentrate on the ASA? Is the site-to-site indeed what I am looking for? Also, what information do I need from the headquarter so that I can configure the remote one (apart from the IP)? Last, does the headquarter need to do anything from their site?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, site-to-site tunnel seems to be the solution you need. The device you install in your branch office could be Cisco ASA or something different, e.g Cisco ISR router (maybe you already have one). The information you'd need from HQ: IP address, networks that are allowed to use tunnel, PreShared Key (if you don't want to use certificate), other Phase 1 and 2 parameters. The same should be set up on the HQ side.

One simple example of such setup: http://bitwizards.com/blog/april-2015/how-to-set-up-a-site-to-site-vpn-with-cisco-asa-55

Khm, now I see you have an answer already  :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a site-to-site VPN is exactly what you are looking for.  You will need to know the crypto key (or have a certificate), isakmp, and ipsec parameters.  If you can get a copy of the asa config (or relevant parts), we can help set up your ASA.